# When to declare a spring bean as private static when the bean is singleton?

Tags: spring

1. What is the impact on declaring the bean as static or non-static?
2. When declaring static methods, the bean cannot be accessed as the bean is not static.

Could somone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us (with code) what you mean by "declaring the bean as static".

Answer (score 2):

If by *declaring the bean as static*, you mean something like

```
@Bean
public static MyBean myBean() {
    return new MyBean();
}
```

then the benefit of this is to have your bean generated before the instance method beans. You would use this for example with a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which states:

> Application contexts can auto-detect BeanFactoryPostProcessor beans in
>   their bean definitions and apply them before any other beans get
>   created.

The Spring Java configuration way for these to be auto-detected and initialized before the rest of your beans is to declare and initialize them with static methods. For example,

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Spring will detect that `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and will use it to

> [resolve] ${...} placeholders within bean definition property values
>   and @Value annotations against the current Spring Environment and its
>   set of PropertySources.

Because these beans are supposed to be initialized before other beans, with instance methods, there is no point being able to access them, so your second point is moot.

Comment: I am referring as below:  public sample { @Autowired private static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; ...internally using the bean in a static method as well as non-static method.} If i am not declaring as static then i cannot able to use the bean in the static method. so i would like to know the differences in the declaration and its benefits

Comment: `@Bean` methods declared as `static` or not will all create objects that will end up in the application context. The only benefit you get from declaring them as `static` is to get them into the application context first. So it has to do with their lifecycle. The beans that you would declare as `static` don't usually need to be able to use other beans (that would be declared as instance methods), so it doesn't matter.

Comment: When i declared as static the problem is autowired is not working..The bean returns null internally in the application code. So my question is does it matters or not when the bean is singleton?

Comment: You're going to have to post another question with your configuration. That has nothing to do with a `static` modifier on `@Bean` declarations.